# Spring-Boot saving all the values except two and putting it as null

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

Kindly look into my code and please help me out on this as i am currently using h2 database and its saving all the data except the Name and the password fields and it is storing it as null

Entity:-

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String Name;
    private String Password;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private int age;
    private char gender;
    private String address;
}
```

UserController:-

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public Users registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody Users users){
        return userService.saveUser(users);
    }
}
```

UserServiceImpl:-

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Users saveUser(Users userModel) {
        return userRepository.save(userModel);
    }
}
```

UserService:-

```
public interface UserService {
    Users saveUser(Users userModel);
}
```

UserRepository:-

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long> {
}
```

it is saving the data in h2 database as this:-
ID      NAME    PASSWORD    ADDRESS     AGE     EMAIL_ADDRESS   GENDER      PHONE_NUMBER
1       null     null    this is my address 10 nitin@gmail.com       M       123456789

Comment: here only the name and password field is storing as null and currently im not using the BcryptPasswordEncoder or any password encoder just wanted to check the working of this but it is storing it as null

Comment: Check if there's a problem with reserved keywords in databases. Rename your variables or give the different column names. That is usually the reason things like that happen. Although usually there should be some error messages along with that.

Comment: i did it but its still the same error i just changed the name to FirstName and the password to UserPassword but its still there    Users(id=1, FirstName=null, UserPassword=null, emailAddress=nitin435@gmail.com, phoneNumber=9546254956, age=10, gender=M, address=this is my address)

Comment: And there is no error in here as im using insomnia its saying 200 Ok

Comment: Edit question to provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the body of the request you send. Also name and password are the only fields, which start with uppercase, it might be a problem with mapping request body to entity.

Comment: Bro seriously this is the only thing that happened now its solved its just that with the uppercase problem in the name and the password field thank you soo much @Chaosfire i was literally stuck on this for about 2 hours now and its solved now thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is in the casing. It should be `name` not `Name` and `password` and not `Password` for the JPA to match the column.

Comment: It worked i was stuck onto this for about 2 hours and it just solved i literally cant thank you enough i was searching about this but found nothing and then you came.